# How to get Schema comment in jdbc？

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I know the postgresql

```sql
select obj_description('some_schema'::regnamespace);
```

But i cannot find any key to get it. (like ResultSet table comment 'REMARKS')

Comment: I don't think the JDBC standard includes the catalog or schema remark in the API. I've seen remarks for tables and columns, though.

Comment: Is there a reason that this is tagged for MySQL and Oracle?  It appears to only concern PostgreSQL